# Android app installer displays wrong information about required disk space

Tags: android, installation

When user selects install packed installer almost always displays information:

> "GameApp could not be viewed. free up some space on your phone and try
>   again"

In this case there is 85 Mb available
space and application after installation takes 23,91 Mb. Installation is possible when is 100 Mb free
space on phone memory.

What's the best way to find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work:

> Try restarting your device and then install the app.

i was encountering the same problem which got solved by doing the above.